# Site searching, auto completion

Tags: search, grails, autocomplete, lucene, google-custom-search

We are building a site that will have a "knowledge centre", that section will contain pdf documents, videos and links to other pages.

We want to add a search feature that will be able to give auto-suggestions/phrase-completion based on the documents, videos and page links.

My first though was to use Lucene, but having a tight deadline someone suggested Google Site Search.

We are using Grails.

How effective will Google site search be? Should Lucene rather be used?

Also, google-cse v2 doesn't allow for onSearchComplete callbacks (as opposed to v1). We have a requirement that if no results are found, it should redirect to a different page.

Thank you.

Comment: GSS search what Google know about your site, Lucene search what you know about your site. You choose.

Comment: Btw, Lucene is a low level tool, take a look at Solr or ElasticSearch instead

Comment: Thanks, yes I was thinking Solr or Grails Searchable Plugin on top of Lucene. I'm trying to weigh it up against dev time vs functionality. I'm sure Lucene would be able to offer much more.

Comment: [Elastic Search plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch), a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a project using Google Search and another using Solr so I can help you to choose:

**Google Search**

- Your site need to be online somewhere so that google bot can index it.
- Your SEO should be good enough.
- The index is built automatically based on page rule (meta name "robot").
- You can provide a sitemap with all pages you want to index.
- Nice backend where you can manage the indexation.
- You need to learn the API a bit if you want to customize search pages layout.
- It's not a free service (starting at 100$ per year for 20 000 queries).

**Solr**

- You have to index your site yourself (but as you control your indexing you have a better control of the content indexed.)
- Then you have to keep the index up-to-date.
- Easy to customize (you can display search result as you want).
- Nice feature included (suggestions, auto-completion,...)
- It's free.

To sum up if you are on a tight schedule Google site search can be faster to implement at first but Solr is much more customizable and free.